# Global variables accessing $var instead of $_GET['var']

Tags: php

I have this very old intranet system, which was implemented I think 6-8 years ago. I encountered some problem since the one that I am using right now is the latest version of PHP, of course some are already deprecated.

I was able to fix/adjust some deprecated php functions, allow php to read short tag `<? ?>`, etc. However there is still one more that I want to fix, but I'm not sure how.

My First plan is to change all global variables to $_GET, but It is very tedious and the fact that I just want to have a running copy in my local. Down grading my PHP version is also not an option because I am also using it on my other projects.

So my question now is, is there a php.ini configuration that I can set so that the system will run without errors/warning and can recognized global variables?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`register_globals` is the configuration switch you are talking about: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

It is deprecated since PHP 5.3.0 and removed since PHP 5.4.0 because it has **serious security issues**. Please do yourself and your client a favor and change all these variables.

Comment: Yup, that is the purpose why I am studying their system (zero documentation urghh) because they want to upgrade it and to add some additional features as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

read

#### http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals

[`more info`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

**Note :**

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
>
> Please note that register_globals cannot be set at runtime ( ini_set()). Although, you can use .htaccess if your host allows it as described . An example .htaccess entry: php_flag register_globals off.