# Pagination won't move through pages

Tags: php, mysql

First off I'm pretty new to MySQl so my code isn't the best.

I'm attempting to add pagination to my search results but I can't figure out why I can't move to the next page. The search results display and it say's page 1 of 3 at the top and shows the next and last links but clicking on the next link wont bring me to page 2. The page number say's it changes in the URL to 2 then 3 but the page doesn't change.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    <?php 

// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error()); 

//This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it to page 1 
if (!(isset($pagenum))) 
{ 
$pagenum = 1; 
} 

//Here we count the number of results 

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players") or die(mysql_error()); 
$rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 

//This is the number of results displayed per page 
$page_rows = 10; 

//This tells us the page number of our last page 
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 

//this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages 
if ($pagenum < 1) 
{ 
$pagenum = 1; 
} 
elseif ($pagenum > $last) 
{ 
$pagenum = $last; 
} 

 //This sets the range to display in our query 

 $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
//This is your query again, the same one... the only difference is we add $max into it

$data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players $max") or die(mysql_error()); 
// Define $color=1 
    $color="1";
    echo '<table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
    echo '<th>ID</th><th>Division</th><th>Club</th><th>Roster Number</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Registered</th><th>Payment</th></th><th>View Player</th><th>Edit Player</th><th>Check Out</th><th>Check In</th><th>Make Badge</th><th>Delete</th>';



//This is where you display your query results

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p)) 

// If $color==1 table row color = #FFC600
    if($color==1){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#C6E7F7'>
    <td><center>".$row['id']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['division']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['club']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['roster_number']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['lname']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['fname']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['registered']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['pay_status']."</center></td><td><center><a href=player_verification.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/view.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=edit_player.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/edit.png height='25' width='25' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=equipment_checkout.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/out-icon.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=equipment_checkin.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/checkin.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=make_badge.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/badge.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=delete.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/delete.gif height='20' width='20' border='0'/></center></td></tr>";
    // Set $color==2, for switching to other color 
    $color="2";
    }
    // When $color not equal 1, use this table row color 
    else {
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
    <td><center>".$row['id']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['division']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['club']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['roster_number']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['lname']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['fname']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['registered']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['pay_status']."</center></td><td><center><a href=player_verification.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/view.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=edit_player.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/edit.png height='25' width='25' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=equipment_checkout.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/out-icon.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=equipment_checkin.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/checkin.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=make_badge.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/badge.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=delete.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/delete.gif height='20' width='20' border='0'/></center></td></tr>";
    // Set $color back to 1 
    $color="1";
    }


// This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages

echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";


// First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.

if ($pagenum == 1) 

{

} 

else 

{

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";

 echo " ";

 $previous = $pagenum-1;

echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";

} 


//just a spacer

echo " ---- ";


//This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links

 if ($pagenum == $last) 

{

} 

else {

$next = $pagenum+1;

echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";

echo " ";

echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";

} 

?>
```

Comment: Please try and break down your code to the relevant parts, e.g. sent sql queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off, you shouldn't be using the `mysql_` functions; they've been deprecated for a while now. That being said, I don't see where you set `$pagenum`, so I assume that's the problem. Add this somewhere before the `if()` that checks `$pagenum`:

```
$pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
```

Of course, you don't want to do that in production, unless you like your database being hacked. Look into `filter_vars` and use either the parameterized `mysqli` functions or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe global variables is not "enable" on the server.

Using register globals has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0 [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11897101/1121982)

Try this way:

instead of this lines:

```
if (!(isset($pagenum))){
    $pagenum = 1;
}
```

use:

```
if (!isset($_GET['pagenum'])){
    $pagenum = 1;
}
else {
    $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
}
```

Comment: Ok I changed the line of code to what you suggested and it still does the same thing, the next button will change the page number in the URL but not move the page and then it wont go any further. If i click the "last" link it will move to the last page in the URL but not on the page itself so clicking next say's its on page 2 but it's not and wont advance to page 3 and clicking last say's it is on page 16 but it's still on page 1

Comment: @user2447848 You will get an error if you not check `pagenum` by `isset($_GET['pagenum'])` when `pagenum` name=value not set in the url.

Answer (score 0):

this is bugfixed and optimized version of your code.

```
<?php 

    // Connects to your Database 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error()); 


    //This is the number of results displayed per page 
    $page_rows = 10;

    //This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it to page 1 
    if (!$_GET['pagenum']) 
        $pagenum = 1;

    //Here we count the number of results 
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 

    //This tells us the page number of our last page 
    $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 

    //this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages 
    $pagenum = max(min($pagenum, $last), 1);

     //This sets the range to display in our query 
     $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

    //This is your query again, the same one... the only difference is we add $max into it
    $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players $max") or die(mysql_error()); 

    ?>
        <table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <th>ID</th><th>Division</th><th>Club</th><th>Roster Number</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Registered</th><th>Payment</th></th><th>View Player</th><th>Edit Player</th><th>Check Out</th><th>Check In</th><th>Make Badge</th><th>Delete</th>
    <?php


    //This is where you display your query results
    $odd = false;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p)) {
        if($odd = !$odd)
            echo "<tr bgcolor='#C6E7F7'>";
        else
            echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";

        echo "<td><center>".$row['id']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['division']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['club']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['roster_number']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['lname']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['fname']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['registered']."</center></td><td><center>".$row['pay_status']."</center></td><td><center><a href=player_verification.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/view.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=edit_player.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/edit.png height='25' width='25' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=equipment_checkout.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/out-icon.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=equipment_checkin.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/checkin.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=make_badge.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/badge.png height='30' width='30' border='0'/></center></td><td><center><a href=delete.php?id=$row[id]><img src=images/icons/delete.gif height='20' width='20' border='0'/></center></td></tr>";
    }


    // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
    echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";

     $previous = $pagenum-1;
     $next = $pagenum+1;

    // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.
    if ($pagenum > 1) 
        echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> &nbsp; <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a>";

    //just a spacer
    echo " ---- ";


    //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links
     if ($pagenum < $last)
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> &nbsp; <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a>";
    ?>
```